# How can I extract specific columns from a list of dataframes with lapply?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list containing nine dataframes (called `data`), each of varying lengths and contents. Consistent across most of them, though, are columns containing information that I want to store in a separate dataframe for later use.
These columns are the following:

`identifiers <- c("Organism Name", "Protein names", "Gene names", "Pathway", "Biological Process")`

I want to iterate through through each element of `data` to check if it contains the columns I'm interested in, then subset these columns as separate dataframes.

I first tried

`lapply(data, '[', identifiers]`

The problem with this is that not all of the dfs contain all of the identifiers listed above, so running this returns 'undefined columns selected'.

My next attempt was

`lapply(data, function(x) if(identifiers %in% x) '[', identifiers)`

which returned a list of 9 (corresponding to the 9 original dataframes)  of class NULL. I think that this general method would work with proper execution, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `identifiers` is a vector of column names, some or all of which may be in each frame, we can do:

```r
lapply(data, function(x) x[,intersect(names(x), identifiers),drop=FALSE])
```

with the understanding that some elements may have zero columns (if none are found).

Your use of `if (identifiers %in% x)` is not quite right for two reasons:

1. `identifiers %in% x` is looking for presence in the data, not in the names, it should be `identifiers %in% names(x)`; and
2. `if` requires exactly one logical, but `identifiers %in% names(x)` is going to return a logical vector the same length as `identifiers` (i.e., not one). It needs to be summarized.

If it is true that if *any* of the columns are found, then you will *always* have *all* of them, then you can change my code above to be

```r
lapply(data, function(x) if (all(identifiers %in% names(x))) data[,identifiers])
```

and frames without those columns will return `NULL`. My use above of `intersect` also works in this regard, the functional difference being in the case where a frame contains some but not all of them. Over to you which logic you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't expect such a quick response, but this is really helpful.